# change colour if word selected array in php

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

i am working for php code 
it's simple i want to show 1 word from Random word for each row in table and want to change the colour.

```
     <?php
  $input = array(
    'Hi',    
    'Welcome',      
  );
  $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

?>
  <b style='color:green;'><?php echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];?> </b>

  <b style='color:red;'><?php echo $input[$rand_keys[1]];?> </b>
```

i want to do one things : if array word reslut = Hi the word should printout with green color if Welcome printout in RED color

please help me how to do this>

ll

Comment: A simple `if-else` will solve that. Check out [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which is great for mixed php/html.

Comment: @El_Vanja Hi i tried several time but no thing is happen this time if statement with array

Comment: Wait, what exactly are you trying to do? Pick 'Hi' or 'Welcome' randomly for X number of `<table>` rows?

Comment: @El_Vanja i have table consist of 5 rows i want randomly to pick up eather Hi or Welcome but with different color 'Hi = Green' ,' Welcome = Red '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that with only two elements in your array array_rand won't be very useful. Try using rand() instead and combine with an if statement.
You can try this out in a php sandbbox [try here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/):

```js
<?php
  $input = array('Hi','Welcome');
  $index = rand(0,1);
  if($input[$index] == "Hi"){ ?> 
     <div style='color:green;'><?php echo $input[0]; ?> </div>
     <div style='color:red;'  ><?php echo $input[1]; ?> </div>
<?php }else if(1==1){?>
     <div style='color:blue;'><?php echo $input[0];   ?> </div>
     <div style='color:blue;'><?php echo $input[1]; } ?> </div>
```

Comment: Uh... this is way off target. And also full of syntax errors.

Comment: But isn't what the OP had in mind. Side notes: check out [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), it's much more frendly for mixed php/html. Also, that `else if(1==1)` is really strange, should simply be `else`.

Comment: code work well , thank you for kind help and everyone

Answer (score 0):

This is the result you already getting:

```
<?php
  $input = array(
    'Hi',    
    'Welcome',      
  );
  $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);

?>
```

This Code is correct.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. OP was asking about conditional styling based on picked value.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a shorthand `if-else` and echo the style for the html tag like this:

```
<b style='color: <?= in_array('Hi', $input) ? 'green' : 'red' ?>'><?= $input[$rand_keys[0]];?> </b>
```

the syntax for this statement is:

```
condition ? true : false
```

Comment: This condition: `in_array('Hi', $input)` makes no sense. It will always be true because `'Hi'` is defined as one of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use assocciative array

```
<?php
    $input = array(
        'green' => 'Hi',    
        'red' => 'Welcome',      
    );
    $keys = array_keys($input); // Makes colors array: green and red
    shuffle($keys);// randomizes colors order
    foreach($keys as $color) {
        echo "<b style='color: $color;'>$input[$color]</b>"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if what you really need is a random greeting with matching color for each row of the table you're building, then you need a function that will be able to pick a random one any time you need it. To get a random entry, we'll make use of [`rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand):

```
function getRandomGreeting(): string
{
    // we immediately define a color for each greeting
    // that way we don't need an if condition later comparing the result we got
    $greetings = [
        ['greeting' => 'Hi', 'color' => 'green'],
        ['greeting' => 'Welcome', 'color' => 'red'],
    ];
    /*
    Here we choose a random number between 0 (because arrays are zero-indexed)
    and length - 1 (for the same reason). That will give us a random index
    which we use to pick a random element of the array.

    Why did I make this dynamic?
    Why not just put 1 if I know indices go from 0 to 1?
    This way, if you ever need to add another greeting, you don't need
    to change anything in the logic of the function. Simply add a greeting
    to the array and it works!
     */
    $chosenGreeting = $greetings[rand(0, count($greetings) - 1)];

    return '<b style="color:'.$chosenGreeting['color'].';">'.$chosenGreeting['greeting'].'</b>';
}
```

And then inside your table, you just need to call the function:

```
<td><?= getRandomGreeting() ?> [...other content of cell...]</td>
```

Note that `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo`.